# Removing event listener in beforeDestroy lifecycle method does not work if element was removed by v-if in a parent component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

Basically I am using a datepicker library that does not emit focus or blur events, so I need to add them manually, but I am having trouble removing the event listeners due to an upstream `v-if`.

I did it like this:

```
<datepicker :id="datePickerId">
```

...

```
computed: {
    datePickerId() { return `date-picker-${this.name}`; },
},

mounted() {
    document.getElementById(this.datePickerId).addEventListener('focus', this.handleFocus);
    document.getElementById(this.datePickerId).addEventListener('blur', this.handleBlur);
},

beforeDestroy() {
    document.getElementById(this.datePickerId).removeEventListener('focus', this.handleFocus);
    document.getElementById(this.datePickerId).removeEventListener('blur', this.handleBlur);
},
```

This works fine until my component is conditionally-rendered via `v-if`, such as:

```
<my-datepicker v-if="isDisplayed">
```

I've researched it, and the problem appears to be because the input element is removed from the DOM due to `v-if` but the Vue instance still exists, so the `beforeDestroy` lifecycle method is called after the element is already gone.

Short of just omitting the cleanup step and relying on modern browser garbage collection, is there any way to prevent memory leaks?

I am extremely interested to learn more about how to gain more control over what is happening around the time `v-if` goes falsy. There isn't many articles/issues/tickets about this "inopportune moment in time", so if anyone has any related input, please feel free to add it.

Is there any other way to tap into the 3rd party library's input's focus/blur events?

> [Vue warn]: Error in beforeDestroy hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this after some quick direction from Chris Fritz from the Vue team. He said look at event delegation, so I found a solution that uses `focusin` and `focusout`.

I had read previously that modern browsers do automatically garbage collect event listeners when DOM elements are removed. Memory leaks are only really an issue with IE7, and Chris said that Vue itself doesn't even support IE7, so an alternate solution does exist where you can just simply not remove event listeners. The `beforeDestroy` lifecycle could be removed.

However, I prefer this solution with event delegation:

Here is the markup that solves the issue:

```
<div @focusin="handleFocus" @focusout="handleBlur">
    <datepicker
        @input="handleChange"
        :name="name"
    ></datepicker>
</div>
```

...

```
methods: {
    handleFocus() { console.log('focus in'); this.$emit('focus'); },
    handleBlur() { console.log('focus out'); this.$emit('blur'); },
},
```

You can read further in the MDN docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event

Also, the problematic datepicker library is called `vuejs-datepicker`, and it's pretty great other than swallowing `focus` or `blur` events.